# JavaScript Making a function that deletes its left

Tags: javascript

How can you delete this or is there another way?

```
a= function() {
    this.delete= function() {
        delete battle;
    }
}
battle = new a();
battle.delete();
```

Comment: `battle = undefined`?

Comment: I'd suggest `this=undefined`

Comment: You can't delete variables at all.

Comment: can you do this=undefined as its not working for me

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish, what is the expected result, and what are you getting instead?

Comment: When Battle.delete(); is run the variable battle is deleted

Comment: It may not matter to you in this case (you may just be asking a hypothetical), but the above code probably wouldn't do you any favors as an example of your work. Monkeying around with reserved words and all that. You might want to look this over carefully:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Foo(battle) {
   this.battle=battle;
   this.distroyBattle=function() {
           this.battle=null;
   }   
}
```